# photocell too sensitive?

Tags: arduino

i use arduino with a photocell module to count the number of blinks of LED, arduino code :

```
attachInterrupt(cds, onPulse, FALLING);
```

sch of CdS module:
[image]
the problem is, for each blink of a LED, the counts is double or sometimes triple, first I suspect is the sensitivity of the CdS, I adjust the trim pot, but it doesn't resolve the problem. I also tried to use a torch, when I light up the torch the count is one, but when I tried to remove the torch away from CdS, the count increase to two. So I suspect is it the whole CdS module but not solely the problem of CdS sensitivity? I tried two new modules, both have same problem. Please advise.

Comment: Attach a scope and look at the signals?

Comment: Keep in mind that a CdS cell will work for blinks (slow enough to count by eye) but is not fast enough to respond to faster signals (maybe hundreds of Hz, maybe thousands, but almost certainly not faster.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your problem will be the interrupt routine can count pulses as short as a microsecond or so and you'll get a couple of transitions when it's right on the edge of detection. Probably the easiest way is to do something like the following to ignore pulses say within 10 milliseconds of each other:

```
volatile uint32_t last_count_ms = 0;

void isr()
{
   if (millis() - last_count_ms < 10)
       return;
   last_count_ms = millis();
   // Do the count here
}
```

Having too many interrupts per second can cause other problems with your system if the CPU ends up spending all its time servicing the interrupt, so the solution Transistor posted is probably a better long-term solution.

Comment: this hack do the trick, a lot easier than the soldering more component. thanks all, but sorry that I didn't try Transistor's post which probably works too , because I am a mechanical guy   not good with soldering and electronics

Answer (score 8):

Most likely you are getting some rapid switching at the threshold level. You need to a little hysteresis to your circuit. Hysteresis is the difference between turn on and turn off and will mean that the signal needs to change significantly before the comparator will change state.

[image]

*Figure 1. Add resistance between (1) and (2).*

Try adding 100k between the points shown in Figure 1.

How it works:

- When light shines on the LDR its resistance will fall. When \$ V_+ \$ input falls below the reference from the pot the output will switch low.
- This will pull \$ V_+ \$ even lower so that the light level will have to fall considerably more before the output will switch high again.

Of course, it should also be possible to scrap the circuit and use the 10k and LDR to feed to an analog input on the micro-controller. The hysteresis could then be handled in software.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it's similar to 'debouncing' a switch, but in this case for light. Same like pressure sensors which can increase a bit and decrease during their (main) increase.

You can use two thresholds (not sure how to implement it electrically), one for counting and stop counting when it's under the lower threshold.

Also, to reduce the sensor, you can stick tape on it (or multiple layers).

Comment: To add to this, you can also filter out any frequency above your LED signal. If you only expect 60kHz and your repeats are 120kHz you can filter that out.